# Using let and const in Lightning Components

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, lightning

Is there any reason why I should not be using let instead of var when writing Lightning Components? I would much rather use let if possible but I dont want to run into any compatibility issues

Comment: I use it in most of my lightning components and have not run into any issues,  it is even used in code snippet samples of the [lightning component developer guide](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/210/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/lightning.pdf).

Comment: not sure if related, but you might find it of interest [Introduction To ECMAScript 6](https://www.salesforce.com/video/303941/) Salesforce Live

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For a while, cross-browser support meant that IE 11 was holding everyone back. There's currently no transpiler (though its been said to be in the works), so if you enabled Extended Internet Explorer 11 mode, be aware that your components may not work in IE 11 if you use let. If you don't support IE 11, then there's no reason to not use it.